# File from client-side fetch request is corrupted on download

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to fetch a file from a `GET` request and download it in the browser, however when the download occurs and I try to open the file, it is apparently corrupted. Images, zipped folders, nothing opens, except for `.txt` files.

This is the fetch request:

```
fetch(this.baseUri + endpointURI)
      .then((res) => res.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        const urlBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
        console.log(urlBlob);
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(urlBlob);
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.setAttribute("download", attachmentName);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();
});
```

I already console logged everything, the blob has size, the response is fine, however when I attempt to open the downloaded file, everything but `.txt` files are apparently corrupted (images, zipped folders, nothing opens).

Comment: I think you can just pass the `blob` resulting from `res.blob()` directly into `createObjectURL`. No need to construct a new one. See [MDN's Examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob#examples).

Comment: Yep, tried that before, same result.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include what you've tried before so that we don't waste our time please.

Comment: StackOverflow is throwing an error when I try to submit the edit, I will keep trying and remove this comment when it works. 
Meanwhile, here's what I tried before:
- Having the response type be arraybuffer instead of blob, then constructing a new blob from it
- Not calling the remove method at the end
- Passing the blob directly instead of constructing a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going for a different approach, here's some context:

My file is fetched by accessing a "middleware" public webservice, that in turn calls the API (this is done to deal with security-related concerns, since the API that accesses the file is a very big monolith that has other integrations that are not necessary for my project. This API is hosted on-premises and making it public is not an option, due to exposing a lot of integrations).

I noticed that the file only came out corrupted when calling the webservice, not when calling the API directly. So I just made it so that when downloading the file, the browser opens another tab with the API endpoint URL, successfully downloading the file (since requests sent from the address bar are CORS-free, and computers accessing it will always be authenticated to access the API).

Since this solution is very specific, I imagine it probably won't be of use to other people, but I will leave the question here regardless.